# User missing in ExecutionContext after Jwt strategy

Tags: nestjs, jwt

Currently I have implemented jwt guard which is working just fine, using Passport, jwt is validating issued tokens and I can pass @Request to see the user via req.user, issue come up after implementing Role based authentication as an addon to the already working guard of jwt.

I followed guidance provided at nestjs.com, however it did not help.
https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Basic roles configuration:

roles.decorator.ts

```js
import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
export const Roles = (...roles: string[]) => SetMetadata('roles', roles);
```

roles.guard.ts

```js
import { Injectable, CanActivate, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
    if (!roles) {
      return true;
    }
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const user = request.user;
    console.log(user);
    const hasRole = () => user.roles.some((role) => roles.includes(role));
    return user && user.roles && hasRole();
  }
}
```

The RolesGuard is Injected in `app.module.ts` content via:

```js
providers: [{
    provide: APP_GUARD,
    useClass: RolesGuard,
  }]
```

My controller header for verification:

```js
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Roles('admin')
  @Get('admin')
  async admin(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.me(req.user);
  }
```

It should check if user provided Bearer token and it is active, jwt will also assign user to Request user, which I can retrieve using `@Request() req` and then `req.user`, however when it comes to `@Roles('admin')`, it returns `undefined` in `roles.guard.ts` 
In section "console.log(user)" so at the end, user is not allowed to see given resource, it seems like `RoleGuard` is Injected before `AuthGuard('jwt')`, however the request has Brearer token inside so it should be converted to user.

I was thinking to change my jwt strategy and implement there CanActivate interface and write it there, but it doesn't sound like good solution to me as I want to keep them separate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm for you that the `RoleGuard` is being called before the `AuthGuard` as the `RoleGuard` is globally scoped to the application (with where you have it defined) and the `AuthGuard` is locally scoped to the function. If you don't mind not having the `RoleGuard` globally scoped and instead scoped against each method, even though it is more code to write, you can add it to the `@UseGuards` decorator. Other than that, like you said, you could merge the two guards into one, but that could get messy and unwieldy.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I wanted to make it global for app however as you said, Roles will be running before the JWT validation, instead of mixing them up I decided to `@UseGuards('jwt',RolesGuard)` which resolve the problem (at least for now, before we go to prod I must figure something else), thank you.